# Multiple for loops for different types of markers - only first loop works

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps

I'm making an app where using Google Maps API I have to display, coordinates of a user displayed in markers, different stores (two types) and projects.
This is the first time Im using js and my approach was fairly a simple one, display all markers for users with for loop, all markers for stores with different for loop and so on...

So far I've done the code for users and started implementing the code for the stores.
I have two for loops (for now) and one of them is always not working. Depends which is the first one in code, but when used individually they work perfectly.

I've tried playing with the variables and giving them different types (let,var, const) thinking that this is where my problem is laying but no progress.
Tried using LatLng object to created latitude and longitude, and also tried typing them manually with values {lat:12312, lng:24141}, still nothing changes.

```
var saloni = <?= $saloni ?>;
//PRODAVNICE
var prodavnice = <?= $prodavnice ?>;
//PROJEKTI PRVA FAZA 
var projekti1 = <?= $projekti1 ?>;
//PROJEKTI DRUGA FAZA
var projekti2 = <?= $projekti2 ?>;
// LOKACIJA SMEDEREVA - CENTAR MAPE
var smederevo = {lat: 44.6659, lng: 20.9335};
// LOKACIJE KOMERCIJALISTE (SAMO KOORDINATE IZ TABELE gps)
var locations = <?=$koordinati?>;
// INFO KOMERCIJALISTE 
var komercijalista = <?= $komercijalista ?>;
//INFORMACIJE LOKACIJA (CELA TABELA gps)
var info = <?= $vreme ?>;
// Po defaultu, content string infoWindow-a izbacuje ovaj string.
var contentString = 'Nema podataka!';


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 5,
  center: smederevo,
});
// Deklarisamo niz u kome ce stojati putanja (lat,lng) za polyline.
var planCoordinates = new Array();


//Pravimo loop koji pravi marker, infoWindow i polylinove za sve koordinate upisane u tabelu gps po zeljenom datumu.
for(let i = 0; i <= locations.length; i++){

let obj = locations[i];
planCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.lat, obj.lng);
let vreme = info[i];

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.lat,obj.lng); 

var myPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: planCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
myPolyline.setMap(map);

infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:contentString.this});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    title:"Markeri",
    zIndex: 999,
});

marker.setMap(map);

 contentString = 'Korisnik: ' + komercijalista.ime + '<br>' + 'Vreme: ' + vreme;

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
infoWindow.setContent('Korisnik: ' + komercijalista.ime + '<br>' + 'Vreme: ' + vreme);
infoWindow.open(map, this);
});

// U slucaju da je menadzer u pitanju, dodaje mu boju, za svakog menadžera druga.
if(komercijalista.uloga == 'Mg1' || komercijalista.uloga == 'Mg2'){

 if(komercijalista.id == 21){ // Boja za Dejana Ilica.
    var boja = "yellow";
 }
 if(komercijalista.id == 43){ // Boja za Ivana M.
     var boja = "green";
 }

// Iscrtavanje simbola za menadžera.
 let ikonica = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    title:"Markeri",
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: 7,
      strokeColor: boja,
      strokeOpacity: 0.7
    }

});
ikonica.setMap(map);
} // END IF MG
} // END FOR LOOP



//KUPCI NA MAPI - START
for(let x = 0; x <= prodavnice.length; x++){

    let prodavnica = prodavnice[x];

    let prod = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: parseFloat(prodavnica.lat), lng: parseFloat(prodavnica.lng)},
    title:"Prodavnice",
    zIndex: 999,
    icon: "{{ asset('/img/pinovi/radnja.png') }}",
    });
    prod.setMap(map);
}

// KUPCI NA MAPI - END




}
```

The map should show both users location and stores, right now it just shows one without the other.

Comment: Have you checked that you are getting multiple points back? Can you log out all points without looping through them?

Comment: Yes. Like I've written, both loops work perfectly when I comment out one of them. 
And yes I can log them without looping through them...

Answer (score 0):

Note that arrays are zero based; you are exceeding the length of your locations when you loop through them in `for(let i = 0; i <= locations.length; i++)` and `for(let x = 0; x <= prodavnice.length; x++)`.

You should loop through these up to their length, i.e. `i < locations.length`. Then both loops should work and you'll see all markers show up on your map.

See the working sample code below (without PHP and dependencies):

```
<div id="map" style="height:600px;"></div>

<script>
    function init() {
        var contentString = 'Nema podataka!';

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 11,
            center: { lat: -33.890542, lng: 151.274856 },
        });

        var planCoordinates = new Array();

        var locations = [
            { lat: -33.890542, lng: 151.274856 },
            { lat: -33.923036, lng: 151.259052 },
            { lat: -34.028249, lng: 151.157507 }
        ];

        var prodavnice = [
            { lat: -33.878665, lng: 151.253980 },
            { lat: -33.871590, lng: 151.270962 },
            { lat: -33.873905, lng: 151.283492 }
        ];

        for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

            let obj = locations[i];
            planCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.lat, obj.lng);
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.lat, obj.lng);

            var myPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: planCoordinates,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
            myPolyline.setMap(map);

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString.this });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                title: "Markeri",
                zIndex: 999,
            });

            marker.setMap(map);

            contentString = 'Korisnik: ';

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent('Korisnik: <br>');
                infoWindow.open(map, this);
            });

            let ikonica = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                title: "Markeri",
                icon: {
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    scale: 7
                }

            });
            ikonica.setMap(map);

        }

        for (let x = 0; x < prodavnice.length; x++) {

            let prodavnica = prodavnice[x];

            let prod = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: parseFloat(prodavnica.lat), lng: parseFloat(prodavnica.lng) },
                title: "Prodavnice",
                zIndex: 999
            });
            prod.setMap(map);
        }

    }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=init"></script>
```

Hope this helps!